# What does lisp "list" function/keyword do?

Tags: list, emacs, lisp, elisp

I've seen it in *An Introduction to Programming in Emacs Elisp*, section 4.4.1:

```
(interactive
  (list (read-buffer
    "Append to buffer: "
    (other-buffer (current-buffer) t))
    (region-beginning)
    (region-end)))
```

It's surprisingly hard to Google what "list" means in lisp, because every page is a hit. I'm guessing it just makes a list of its arguments, in which case, why is it better or clearer to use than just making a list "manually" with another set of parentheses?

Comment: Emacs Lisp comes with a manual: https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Building-Lists.html#Building-Lists

Comment: Emacs has online help: control-h f list

Comment: @RainerJoswig thanks. I was only able to find that after reading the posted answer, given that it's hard to search the manual for "list."

Comment: This manual's index is here and it has an entry for LIST: https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Index.html#Index

Comment: So you think searching for `{` would be easier? In many languages the same is also done with a constructor. Eg. Java `interactive(new LinkedList(Array.asList(getBuffer( "Append to buffer", otehrBuffer(currentBuffer(), true), regionBeginning(), regionEnd()))));`

Comment: @Sylwester no, I thought asking a question on SO would be easier...

Comment: "*No, I thought asking a question on SO would be easier...* - Easier for **you**, maybe, and in the short run only, IMO. You will help yourself and help others help you (especially for more important problems that you encounter) if you learn to **ask Emacs**. `C-h i`; `i` to search the index; `C-h f`, `C-h v`, `C-h m`,...

Comment: @Drew thanks, mind posting that as an answer so if someone else Googles "what does the lisp list function do?" they can learn this as well?

Comment: @Drew for plausibility's sake, as someone who is used to programming languages with a strong separation of functions / keywords, it's not obvious to associate a keyword-like function like *list* with something in the *function help* manual. That would be very useful to explain in an answer. The downvotes lack the empathy for actually learning elisp and are not warranted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because you *cannot* just use "another set of parentheses" to make a list.

Here's an expression that creates a list containing the numbers 1, 2, 3, 4.

```
(list 1 2 3 4)
```

However, you cannot use `(1 2 3 4)` or even `((1 2 3 4))` to express that.

Comment: What is `(1 2 3 4)` then?

Comment: Oh right, 1 would be evaluated as a function and that would fail. Does `'(1 2 3 4)` work as well?

Comment: @djechlin `'(1 2 3 4)` is a datum literal. You can't evaluate expressions in it. e.g., `'((+ 1 2) 3 4)` is a datum literal for the list `((+ 1 2) 3 4)`, not `(3 3 4)`.

Answer (score 2):

`list` is an essential function that is shared between all major dialects of Lisp. While not itself being a primitive it's actual implementation is the ability of the implementation to have [varargs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Varargs). It has been around since [LISP 1.5 from 1962 (page 47)](http://www.softwarepreservation.org/projects/LISP/book/LISP%201.5%20Programmers%20Manual.pdf) (In 1960 LISP1 had it as [a special form (page 121)](http://history.siam.org/sup/Fox_1960_LISP.pdf))

Its implementation in Common Lisp and Emacs Lisp is:

```
(defun list (&rest args)
  args)
```

Emacs Lisp cannot replace it with syntax since it doesn not have reader macros but Common Lisp can introduce new syntax in place of writing `(list ..)`. An example how to do it in Common Lisp:

```
(defun read-list (stream char)
   (declare (ignore char))
   (cons 'list (read-delimited-list #\} stream t)))

(set-macro-character #\{ #'read-list)
(set-macro-character #\} (get-macro-character #\)))

{(+ 4 5) 'test {1 2 3}} 
; expands to: (list (+ 4 5) 'test (list 1 2 3))
; ==> (9 test (1 2 3))
```

The result would be confusion for other lispers when they get introduced to the code so it really have to be very valuable to counter the drawback. Clojure has introduced special syntax for arrays and maps but [still use `list` to make lists](http://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/list).